# Update Description Project Field

Tags: acumatica

I would like to update this field, impossible, is it related to multilanguage field ?

[image]

I try with this syntax :

```
protected void PMProject_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
{
  var row = (PMProject)e.Row;
  if (row!=null)
  {
    string newdescription=undevis.Subject;
    row.Description="[{en:"+newdescription+"}]";
 }
```

Thanks, Xav

Comment: Why not just set  row.Description = newdescription ?

Comment: When I do this, I have nothing ! No description on the screen.